# Powershell and dollar sign in argument

Tags: windows, powershell

Let's assume my script is the following:

```
param([string]$password)
Write-Host $password
```

This will return if I launch it this way:

```
.\myDollarParam.ps1 -Password Pa$sword
 Pa
```

I would like the following output:

```
 Pa$sword
```

Is there a way to do that aside using ` or \ in the argument ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

The easy way is to enclose it in single quotes. For ex.:

```
.\myDollarParam.ps1 -Password 'Pa$sword'
```

Otherwise PowerShell interprets the "$" as the start of a variable, so what you are basically saying in your example, is assign the variable the value "Pa" and then the value stored in the variable "$sword"

A to prove this theory running the following gives me the interesting result:

```
$sword = "Stuff"
.\myDollarParam.ps1 -Password Pa$sword
PaStuff
```

By enclosing in single quotes, you are saying pass the literal characters in this string.

The "proper" way to do passwords is to use the ConvertTo-SecureString cmdlt.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how do I get from this: `$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -asplaintext -force` to a string ? I get this when I print $password `System.Security.SecureString`

Comment: @HelloToTheWorld That's a different question entirely. Post a new question, you'll get an answer good and fast.

Comment: To convert from a secure string back to text isn't easy. Here is a link to the code for a function that does it: [link](http://pastebin.com/yPAYBGpH)